# "I never was" vs. "I was never"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-order, negation

What is the difference between "I never was" and "I was never"? It seems that there is a subtle difference, but I can't quite grasp it. Is one of them informal?

For example:

> - I never was a good cook.
> - I was never a good cook.

Comment: Can you give us more context, examples of how you would use each variation?

Comment: Say, I never was a good cook, and I was never a good cook.

Comment: Never was I more sure that there is no difference.

Comment: @ewormuth - In this case, the OP can't provide context, because that's exactly what s/he is requesting!

Comment: I guess I was feeling as @tchrist did -- there's not much difference between them.  If I had another sentence, maybe I would see what the difference was.

Comment: @tchrist The first is more emphatic a denial, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

> I never was a good cook.

Possible context: Lisa's mother-in-law has pressured her to prepare Thanksgiving dinner for the extended family.  Lisa has reluctantly agreed.  She made an honest try but made a key mistake and the turkey was a failure.  "Well, you know, I never was a good cook."

> I was never a good cook.

Possible context: Margaret, in her eighties and living in a nursing home, is being interviewed by a gerontology student.  She confides to the student, "I was never a good cook."

Answer (score -1):

I never was a good cook. That sentence shows me that negative emotional answer which means the person never become a good cook. Whereas the other sentence;

I was never a good cook. Shows me that the person is denying something, he knowns already by using no.

Answer (score -1):

> "I never was that vulnerable"

Here we are highlighting the never. A strong emotion of past. Now, I am vulnerable, and it seems not good. A negative emotion.

> "I was never that vulnerable."

Here it is lacking that strong emotion and is more like a simple statement. I'm vulnerable now, but it's no big deal.

> Both mean the same but it's little decoration to highlight negative emotion.